# i want to scale bitmap on ACTION_MOVE android

Tags: android, bitmap, action, android-canvas

I want to scale view on touch event of ACTION_MOVE.[image: when i drag orange square image according to that red ball should be resized. red bal resized from its center point to center of orange square image o][image: output of image like this]

all bitmap are in square format. (point1= top+left, point2 =top+right, point3=bottom+left, point4=bottom+right)
i got the all four points.
when i drag the yellow gripper on top of the bitmap , red ball resize according to that (gripper can be move at any direction).

my question:
--> how should i calculate the distance of gripper center point and bitmap (left+top) point1 and scale according to bitmap.

means if i drag the bitmap from top+left corner then it scale/resize from point1,point2,point4 only (bottom+right corner remail at its position).

--> i am using canvas to draw bitmap, is it the rightway to handle bitmap scale/rotate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the x,y coordinates on the event ACTION_DOWN and the x',y' coordinates on ACTION_UP. With the two points, you can make your measures (Euclidean Distance, for example).

```
gripper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            x1 = event.getX();
            y1 = event.getY();
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            x2 = event.getX();
            y2 = event.getY();
        }               
        return false;
    }           
});
```

You can also get the left,top position of the bitmap with `getLeft()`,`getTop()` methods (but note that these methods return the position relative to the View's parent layout).

There is an Matrix parameter on the createBitmap method that will allow you to resize your Bitmap and so you can store it with the resolution you want. See how [here](http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html) (it's an excellent tutorial, by the way). You probably already know how to do that, but I see no problem in sharing it anyway =P.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for replying.createBitmap  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width() exception, i have used createScaledBitmap fuction and it works fine but problem is when i scale(re-size) round bitmap, it scale as arc square bitmap. Any sol. ?

Comment: this is what i hv used as u say : Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, getX(), getY(),
//     width, height, matrix, true); where getX() and getY() is my current bitmap position on canvas. sorry for comment format.

Comment: It seems that there is a mistake in your code. Look at the link that i posted again. You should do "Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, bitmapOrg.width(), bitmapOrg.height, matrix, true);" always... the "matrix" parameter is the one that holds the actual desired scale, like this "matrix.postScale((((float) newWidth) / width), (((float) newHeight) / height))". The comment format doesn't help much with the explanations =/ ... so take your time at the link that I posted and work with the Matrix's parameters only so to get your resize.

Comment: ok. its works.But when i re-size(stretch) my bitmap it lose its resolution, means is not like an original bitmap, can i remain its resolution anyway ?

Comment: If the resized bitmap has a larger resolution than the original one, the transformation will be lossy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6190/discussion-between-hiren-dabhi-and-alesqui)